# how to install packages on ubuntu 10.10 offline?

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

I googled and found keryx(http://keryxproject.org/) but there is no download for x64. so if other alternative is available please make me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a DVD image [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/maverick/release/) and add it as a package source using [apt-cdrom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptCdrom).